# Getting the first element in a string array which is inside a arraylist. C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

In one of my web application page, I have a C# code as follows. How do I get the first element in the string array inside the arraylist?

**Code**

```
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Array test[9] = new Array();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();


        list.Add(new string[] { "1", "Test1", "20", "30" });
        list.Add(new string[] { "2", "Test2", "5", "30" });
        list.Add(new string[] { "3", "Test3", "10", "30" });
        list.Add(new string[] { "4", "Test4", "20", "30" });
        list.Add(new string[] { "5", "Test5", "0", "30" });
        list.Add(new string[] { "6", "Test6", "15", "30" });
        list.Add(new string[] { "7", "Test7", "10", "30" });
        list.Add(new string[] { "8", "Test8", "20", "30" });
        list.Add(new string[] { "9", "Test9", "30", "30" });

        LabelMessages.Text = "Number of Items: " + list.Count + " Item 1 record 1: " + list[1];


    }
```

**Expected Output**

```
Number of Items: 9 Item 1 record 1: 1
```

**Current Output (which is not what I want)**

```
Number of Items: 9 Item 1 record 1: System.String[]
```

So, suppose that the following code:

```
list.Add(new string[] { "1", "Test1", "20", "30" });
```

is change to:

```
list.Add(new string[] { "Test1", "20", "30" });
```

then the expected output should be:

```
Number of Items: 9 Item 1 record 1: Test1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the first element of string array and each element of list present a string array so you have to type cast the list element to string array and later access the first element of array. This `((string[])list[0])[0]` will give you first element of array at zero locaation of list.

You are using `ArrayList which is not generic list`, you may use `List which is generic list` and you will be `free from type casting`.

```
LabelMessages.Text = "Number of Items: " + list.Count + 
                     " Item 1 record 1: " +( (string[])list[0])[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

the expression list[1] will return a type of **Object** which currently is a **string array**.

Since it is an Object, you will not be able to directly index it like *list[1][1]* . you have to explicitly convert it into string array before you can index it.

((string[])list[1])[1];

You can use it like this

```
LabelMessages.Text = "Number of Items: " + list.Count + " Item 1 record 1: " +  ((string[])list[1])[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can acheive reverse parsing you can get the element.

((string[])list[0])[0]